# List start & end date of each week in a year dynamically

Tags: php, date, datetime, php-carbon

How can i get list of all Weeks in a Year and each weeks Start and End date dynamically ?

**Each week Day should start from Monday**

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @AmitRajput I've done by myself. See below my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
$year = 2016;

$weeksOfYear = new DatePeriod(
    new DateTime("$year-1 monday"),
    new DateInterval('P1W'),
    new DateTime("$year-12-31")
);

$weekCounter = 1;

foreach ($weeksOfYear as $startOfWeek) {

    echo "Week $weekCounter => "
        . "(start): "
        . $startOfWeek->format('Y-m-d')
        . " - (end): "
        . $startOfWeek->modify('+6 days')->format('Y-m-d')
        . "<br>";

    $weekCounter ++;
}
```

Output:

```
Week 1 => (start): 2016-01-04 - (end): 2016-01-10
Week 2 => (start): 2016-01-11 - (end): 2016-01-17
Week 3 => (start): 2016-01-18 - (end): 2016-01-24
...
Week 51 => (start): 2016-12-19 - (end): 2016-12-25
Week 52 => (start): 2016-12-26 - (end): 2017-01-01
```

Comment: Thx for the reply, but unfortunately it's not working for year 2015, coz it has 53 week :(

Answer (score 1):

```
    $weeks_arr = array();
    $temp1 = Carbon::now();
    $temp2 = Carbon::now();
    $start_date = $temp1->startOfWeek()->subYear()->addDay();
    $end_date = $temp2->endOfWeek()->addWeek();

    if ($start_date->weekOfYear != $end_date->weekOfYear) {
        $start_date->addWeek();
    }
    while ($start_date < $end_date) {
        $weeks_arr[$start_date->weekOfYear]['week'] = $start_date->weekOfYear;
        $weeks_arr[$start_date->weekOfYear]['start'] = $start_date->startOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d');
        $weeks_arr[$start_date->weekOfYear]['end'] = $start_date->endOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d');

        $start_date->addWeek();
    }
    return $weeks_arr;
```